# rostopic navigation_velocity_smoother/raw_cmd_vel

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am implementing navigation stack on my robot and using move_base to move the robot. The move base node is publishing Twist messages on rostopic navigation_velocity_smoother/raw_cmd_vel. Can anyone describe what this topic is for ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233233/rostopic-navigation_velocity_smoother/raw_cmd_vel/) by [b2meer](https://answers.ros.org/users/25523/b2meer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2016-04-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure which velocity_smoother you're referring to, but this package has documentation for the topics: http://wiki.ros.org/yocs_velocity_smoother

The velocity smoother is designed to smooth out potentially jerky commands to keep a robot from rocking around if the user is too aggressive with the joystick.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [b2meer](https://answers.ros.org/users/25523/b2meer/) on 2016-05-08**:
Thanks for your response. I will look into this package.